# how can i reduce the time lag to execute an adb shell command to perform swipe input on my android device

Tags: android, shell, adb

I want to input swipe commands back to back using a c program and adb shell to my android device .
But the lag between the commands is preventing me from achieving my goal.
Is there anyway to reduce this lag??

Answer (score 3):

You can record some input and repeat it directly.
For example:

Record:

```
cat /dev/input/event0 > inputdata
```

Replay:

```
cat inputdata > /dev/input/event0
```

To find the correct event number you can use the `getevent -p` command.

Comment: This appears to stopped working in Android 11 as write access to /dev/input/ has been restricted.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "lag between the commands". The `input` command is a java application and it takes about a second (depending on your device) to launch it. So you can not inject 2 events back to back faster than that.

You could either write your own `input` command which would accept multiple sets of coordinates in one take thus eliminating the need to run the command multiple times. Or you could use series of `sendevent` commands for emulating your gesture instead.